# Looking for free Bluray media player application alternative to VLC for Windows 10

Tags: windows, optical-media, vlc, video-player

I have a Bluray disk reader installed in my PC however the open source VLC player will not play a Bluray disk. A DVD disk in the Bluray player works fine however if I try to play a Bluray disk with VLC an error dialog displays saying that it can not find the aacs library for decoding the Bluray media.

This is a known issue with the VLC player and I found a number of web forums that provided the necessary steps and links to the appropriate aacs library dll and the key database.

However I could not get it to work and have given up on that approach.

So I am looking for an alternative application that I can install under Windows 10 and will play Bluray disk media such as movies.

Comment: There are non. Bluray disks use proprietary DRM systems and encryption keys to prevent any non registered software from reading them, to prevent piracy. There is MakeMKV which is able to rip them to MKV format as an alternative.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos on the forums where I found info about VLC with Bluray there were a number of postings where people indicated that performing the procedure worked for them. Some people had problems with the aacs library dll in that the 64 bit version would not work but the 32 bit version would. And here is a posting that claims VLC with a plug-in will play Bluray https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/26385/looking-for-media-player-for-windows-8-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking around I have downloaded and am using the Leawo Bluray player application with Windows 10 and an LG Bluray device and a Viewsonic 1920x1080 display through DVI cable.

http://www.leawo.org/blu-ray-player/

It has been working fine with standard Bluray disks. I have not tried it with 3D Bluray nor with a 2K or 4K display though the download page claims that 4K is supported. It does not mention 3D Bluray.

The user interface is a bit strange in that there is a kind of virtual remote used for moving through menus rather than just clicking directly with the mouse however it works.

**Note: This player displayed an advertisement in the default web browser the last time I used it.**

Here are the technical stats for this player software. Not sure if there is a Mac version or not.

[image: screen shot of Leawo Bluray player technical requirements and supported protocols]